# which Class and API is best for background activity in Android development?

Tags: java, android, api

There are Like Executor, ThreadPool and FutureTask on Android official website because AsyncTask is deprecated. In advance and later on which API should i use later. Can't use Kotlin concurrency right now because I'm learning in java.

Comment: The only valid answer to this question is "it depends" :-) You can also use `Service`. This is a question that will generate a bunch of answers which are mostly opinions. Pick something and use it and don't worry about it. Once you have used some of these mechanisms  you will understand when to use what.

Comment: Ok so which thing should I go first right now Service, Executor or Volley because my friend says you should start with executor or Volley

Comment: Well, Volley is for background network I/O. Thread pools (Executor) and `Service` can do all kinds of processing in the background. If your background processing involves fetching some data from a server then you can use Volley if you want, as it does a lot of stuff for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is opinion based so might be closed by others later but:

Honestly... Coroutines are the only thing I suspect will be useful in the future.
If you can't use them right now, use whatever is the easiest to use in the specific case you have. There are lots of things you could learn but learning e.g. RxJava won't be worth it.

I really really suggest to spend the time you would use on learning one of the things you mentioned on Kotlin instead (once you know Java a bit the basics should take around the same time, including coroutines might double that time).

As I said, learning something else isn't worth it in my opinion. If you just have a simple use case I'd argue use whatever you can learn the fastest (even if that is Asynctask with deprecation warnings removed) and then switch to Kotlin as soon as possible and replace that AsyncTask. Otherwise you'll likely waste most of the time

Even Google said that Kotlin comes before Java for Android now, so Java might be good while starting out with a programming language and old courses but you should switch as soon as you can

Comment: Nicely said! and one thing more what about the external libraries or API like volley :-)

Comment: Retrofit is great. If you need to have a Database combine that with Room

Both take some time to learn as a beginner but will also save you a lot of time for sure.

Retrofit+Kotlin concurrency (coroutines, suspend functions) is even better

Comment: Glide or Picasso can be used if you need to load images from the web dynamically, I think those are all of the important libraries

Comment: Again Thanks for your kind info!

Comment: No problem, glad I helped :D